# Adding Web Mapping Service with leaflet for interactive map

Tags: r, leaflet, shinydashboard

I have issues in adding a WMS layer of my country with addWMSTiles.

I only see the Open Street basemap but not the WMS layer.

Would you know why ?

Thank you very much.

This is my Ui.R :

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
   dashboardHeader(
     title = "New Caledonia",
     titleWidth = 500),

    dashboardSidebar(
      sidebarMenu(
        id = "Menu1",
        menuItem(strong("Map"), tabName = "Map", icon = icon("globe"),selected = TRUE)
      )
    ),

    dashboardBody(
      tags$head(tags$style(HTML('
                          .main-header .logo {
                          font-family: "Georgia", Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
                          font-weight: bold;
                          font-size: 16px;
                          }
                          '))),

  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "Map",
            fluidRow(

              box(
                title = "Map test",
                collapsible = TRUE,
                width = "100%",
                height = "850px",
                solidHeader = TRUE,
                status = "primary",
                leafletOutput("mymap",width="100%",height="850px"))
            )
       )
     )
   )
 )
```

And this is my Server.R :

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(height = "100%") %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      setView(165.538323, -21.403740, zoom = 8) %>%
      addWMSTiles(
        "https://carto.gouv.nc:443/public/services",
        layers = "fond_imagerie",
        options = WMSTileOptions(format = "image/png", transparent = TRUE),
        attribution = "Gouvernement de la Nouvelle-Calédonie"
    )
  })
})
```

If you have an idea, please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: You are adding both the OSM tiles and the WMS tiles. Have you tried adding **only** the WMS tiles?

Comment: Thank you very much for replying, but even if I remove the "addTiles() %>%" line, it does not work. Thank you anyway.